# gitlab impossible to remove distant files

Tags: git, remote-server, git-push, git-commit

I've just started using **gitlab** and I have a branch synchronized with my local folder.

I made some manual adjustments and now I have an extra distant folder which I can't delete.
When I use git push, it tells me I'm up to date.
When I use git fetch, up to date.

If I use git add `-u`, `git add -A`, `git gc --prune=now`, `git rm -r path/.`, or other obscur formulas nothing happens, I get an extra folder online.

How can I re-compare the two folders from scratch and run an update in one direction or another?

Answer (score 0):

Git has his own remove command: `git rm`. First run `git pull origin master` to retrieve all the changes, then run

```
git rm -r my_folder
git commit -m 'Remove my_folder'
git push origin master
```

Comment: yes, I did try that too but it's not working. Is there not a way to  discard everything and restart from scratch?